# ClientAbortException when executing angular 2 post in tomcat

Tags: tomcat7, angular, resteasy

After completing the quickstart of angular 2 app i tried to execute a post to a rest web service deployed in another server, which is tomcat.
I have added an OPTIONS method to allow all origins. After returning from the getOptions() method it enters the getTestResponse method and a 
ClientAbortException occurs.

Sample code :

```
return this._http.post(url, body, options)
            .map(res => res.json());
```

Web service code :

```
@OPTIONS
@Path("samplePath")
public Response getOptions() {
return Response.ok()
.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT")
.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding")
.build();
}

@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public TestResponse getTestResponse(TestRequest testRequest) {

//somehow get response from database
//
}
```

Do you have any idea why this exception could occur?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No, only that post has failed, with below warning Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/... (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because here you add headers just to your option request.

But actually POST is failing.

To fix issue, best is to add a CORS filter to your application which will be applied to all requests.

[CorsFilterApi](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/interceptors/CorsFilter.html)

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.CorsFilter;

@ApplicationPath(RestApplication.ROOT_PATH)
public class RestApplication extends Application {

    public static final String ROOT_PATH = "/resources";

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();


    ...



    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {

        CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter();
        corsFilter.getAllowedOrigins().add("*");
        corsFilter.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsFilter.setAllowedHeaders("origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        corsFilter.setAllowedMethods("GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        singletons.add(corsFilter);

        return singletons;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Solution 2 apply headers just to your post request and 
make sure that your @OPTION REQUEST IS NOT CONTAINING @PATH 
because then it's not same request in your case:

```
@OPTIONS
public Response getOptions() {
return Response.ok()
.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT")
.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding")
.build();
}

@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getTestResponse(TestRequest testRequest) {

  return Response.ok()
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS").build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. I will try it immediately.

Comment: I am currently using 2x version of reasteay in servlet 2.0. Is there another cors filter example except javax.servlet.Filter ?

Comment: hey then apply just headers to your POST response as well and it will work.